# MySQL get rows from table that include a BIGINT specified in a passed-in array

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript

I have recently struck an issue with mysql using `serverless-mysql` in TypeScript where potentially my query is incorrect? I am using the following to create the query:

```
export default async function ExcuteQuery(query: any, values: any) {    
    try {        
        const results = await db.query(query, values);
        await db.end();        
        return results;
    } catch (error: any) {
        throw new Error(error.message + error.stack)
    }
  }

let ids: BigInt[] = [222222222222222222222, 3333333333333333333333, 444444444444444444444]
ExcuteQuery("SELECT * FROM servers WHERE id IN (?)", [ids.join()])
```

Which returned an empty array with no row data inside.

However, when I tried using the query inside phpmyadmin, like so:

```
"SELECT * FROM servers WHERE id IN (222222222222222222222, 3333333333333333333333, 444444444444444444444)"
```

It returned the rows as I would like them, no troubles.
Does this mean I am doing something wrong with the parameter data that I am passing into that query? Is it a type cast issue? I am more then happy to elaborate if that was not clear, just feel free to comment!

I appreciate any responses I get in advance, thank you!

I have attempted to change the parameter data using attempts like:

```
[ids.join(', ')]
[`(${ids.join()})`]
```

However, none of those seemed to work either.

Comment: `?` is the placeholder for _one_ value. By passing your joined IDs, you are effectively looking for a record where that column contains the value `222222222222222222222,3333333333333333333333,444444444444444444444` - which does not exist. You need to create your query dynamically, `WHERE id IN (?, ?, ?)` - with as many placeholders as you have IDs, and then bind your IDs to them one by one.

Comment: ``.. WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, ?)``. But this will be slow. I recommend you to parse provided single CSV to separate values in the subquery.

Comment: _The point_ of prepared statements is that they separate query syntax, from data. The commas in `IN(1, 2, 3)` are part of the _syntax_. You can not "insert" _syntactical_ parts of the query via placeholders, _only_ the actual data values.

Comment: @Akina that worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: @CBroe the array can be at one time up to 200 ID's long, how would I go about adding the ?'s to the query for each ID if that is the case?

Comment: *that worked* But this code pertforms full table scan.

Comment: @Akina I don't do alot with Databases, how do you go about finding said ID's in the table, without doing a full table scan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT servers.* 
FROM servers
JOIN JSON_TABLE(CONCAT('[', ?, ']'), 
                '$[*]' COLUMNS (id BIGINT PATH '$')) criteria USING (id)
```

Comment: So this is a more performant way of achieving .. WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, ?), as stated in the comments above?

Comment: @danw0001 Of course this is more fast solution..